# Multiple postgres sequences for each foreign key

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm using postgres 14 and my invoice table looks something like that:

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| location_id | uuid |
| invoice_id | int |
| ... | ... |

> The `location_id` is a foreign key from the location table. `location_id` and `invoice_id` are a composite primary key.

What I want to achieve now is that the invoice id for each location starts at 1 and increments automatically.
Is there a way to implement this with something like a sequence?

Comment: Probably not, usually an invoice_id is not allowed to have gaps like 1, 5, 6, 9. It MUST be  1, 2, 3, 4 and a sequence can't/doesn't guarantee this. You have to lock the table, get the MAX() id and do a + 1 to create a new id.

Comment: Or use something like [this](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/gapless-sequence/) which avoids locking the whole table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a before insert trigger:

```
create or replace Function private.invoice_before_insert()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
  begin
    new.invoice_id = (
      select coalesce(max(invoice_id), 0) + 1
      from private.invoice
      where invoice_location_id = new.invoice_location_id
    );
    new.invoice_created_at = current_timestamp;

    return new;
  end;
$$;

create trigger invoice_before_insert
before insert
on private.invoice
for each row
execute function private.invoice_before_insert();
```

> I'm not sure if this aprouch has any drawbacks tho. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You will have to use the `serializable` isolation level for all transactions in order to make this work. Or completely lock the table when doing an INSERT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you have any article link or something else, to explain why i should use the serializable isolation level for all transactions or lock the table. It's not quite clear to me.

Comment: If two transactions insert a row at the same time, both will see the same max() value